# Adding ActiveX DLL to C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and have a number of DLL's that i need to add as refernces in my project. The references need to be of File Type ActiveX but whenever i add the reference to the project they just show as a .net class library.

I'Ve tried adding them as COM Components but it says the files cannot be loaded, i know the files are correct as i can see in another project on the same machine that they've been loaded.

Does anyone know how i can reference these DLL's as ActiveX file type?

Thanks.

Comment: That's entirely normal, an ActiveX control requires an AxHost and an Interop wrapper to function inside a Winforms project.  Just google the exception you get, hundreds of thousands of hits and you don't need one more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register each dll with regsvr32 "path_to_the_dll".
After that, you can add it as COM.